# Dockerfile Copy a File Create a Folder

Tags: docker

Estou usando o Docker-Composer para fazer um projeto, mas no Dockerfile, quando uso o COPY do arquivo composer.json, ele cria uma pasta chamada composer.json

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

docker-compose:

````
version: '3.8'

services:
  apache:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - serverNetwork
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    container_name: Apache
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - /public/:/var/www/html/
      - /app/:/var/www/
networks:
  serverNetwork:
    driver: bridge```



Dockerfile:

```Dockerfile

FROM php:apache
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY composer.json .
````

Verificando se está tudo certo com o COPY

```
docker exec -it Apache /bin/bash 
cat composer.json
cat: composer.json: Is a directory
```

Comment: Poderia tentar novamente desta forma: `COPY composer.json composer.json`

Comment: @Danizavtz Ele nem copia desse jeito (Não da nenhum erro, mas quando entro no container, não tem nenhum composer.json - Nem uma pasta e nem um arquivo)

Comment: O ideal seria fazer o debug do `Dockerfile` com o `docker-compose` desligado. O problema de analisar com o `docker-compose` ativo é que você possui um volume mapeado.  Por causa dessa linha:  `- /app/:/var/www/` o que pode levar a um comportamento inesperado.

Comment: E talvez o fato de usar `volumes` é que esteja causando o comportamento que está reportando.